# How can I see all errors in a Go project with LSP mode?

Tags: spacemacs, flycheck, lsp-mode

When opening a Go project with LSP mode, spacemacs / `flycheck` only shows errors in the current package, not including tests files. For example, in the following project:

```
|- pkg1
|- pkg2
|- cmd
```

When I'm in the `pkg1/file.go` file all of the following functions won't display errors from `pkg2`, `cmd` nor test files in `pkg1`:

- `next-error`, `flycheck-next-error`, `flycheck-projectile-list-errors`, `flycheck-list-errors`.

The only function which displays all error is: `lsp-treemacs-errors-list`, but it's not very friendly: there is no way to jump to the next error without going to the `lsp-treemacs-errors-list buffer`, scrolling, unfolding and entering the error.

My setup: emacs 26.3, spacemacs @develop (latest), go layer with LSP mode + flycheck layer. (LSP mode works perfectly).

Comment: I'm also looking for this. In particular, I'm looking for an `lsp-next-error` function, or alternatively, for opening `lsp-treemacs-errors-list` to inform `next-error`, so that `next-error` descends the list of reported errors. Did you find anything in your travels, Robert?

Comment: I'm looking for this too. Found a discouraging open issue: https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/382

Comment: @sircolinton unfortuantely I didn't find anything better. `flycheck-list-errors` only inspects errors in the currently open file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package [`flycheck-projectile`](https://github.com/nbfalcon/flycheck-projectile) which lists all errors in the package.[image: example]

It takes a bit of time to load, but then in watches for changes and it's very fast.